# How to use PromQL to show distinct 'version' label over time?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

If I have a Prometheus metric that includes application version as a label, how can I expose that in a Grafana table to see when a version was deployed over time?

```
app_info{version="1.0"} 1.0
```

I would love to generate a table chart in Grafana that shows what versions were deployed over the query timeframe (without the duplication between):

```
| Time           | Version    |
| 4/1 8:00am     | 1.0        |
| 4/2 8:15am     | 1.3        |
| 4/4 9:00am     | 2.0        |
```

Comment: How your metric looks like? Is it's gauge? When you export it?

Comment: See the `app_info` metric above. It would be a gauge that always reports 1.0.

Comment: Have you tried sum by (version) (app_info)?

Comment: @SergioSantiago That creates a table with the values for every time, but the table shows the time for all the values. I'm only interested i when the `version` changes. (Similar to a SQL `distinct`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus take a metric with changing labels as several independent metrics. So you are actually trying to display three metrics' last value (with it's timestamp).

If you are using... grafana 7.0+ IIRC, you can use Transform to achieve that. Simply query `app_info`, then add `Group by` plugin, then Group by `version`, and Calculate the `Last` value of `Time`, display the result as Table panel.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer! I changed from `Last` to `First` to more accurately match when the version first was deployed.